# iOS App being rejected by apple straight after upload - Invalid Image

Tags: iphone, ios, image

Evening,

Going crazy about this, getting the following message straight after upload.

I've checked the icons, the icon file names in the info.plist, launch images, image compression etc

Any ideas what i've missed?

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "APP X". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Invalid Image - For iOS applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the PNG format.

If your application supports the iPhone device family, you must include a square icon of exactly 57x57 pixels.
If your application supports the iPad device family, you must include a square icon of exactly 72x72 pixels.
For Mac OS X applications, icons included in the binary submission must be in the ICNS format and must include a square 512x512@2x image.
Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: confirm that the icon images are included in the target you are building. Also, icon images must be in the top level directory of your project

Comment: Just moved now, cleaned and rebuilding. Hope it's as easy as that..

Comment: Afraid it's the same.... :-(

Comment: Check your project files and also the project files in the folder  on your computer, make sure there are no other icon images available that are not in png format. If nothing works remove all of the icon images, before you do that make sure you have a copy on your computer so you can re create them. then delete them from and remove all the references from the project. Clean and re build. Make sure the new icons are the only ones available. Make sure they are in top level and then try it again. Make sure all icon images are in png format.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Checked.. No rouge .jpg's just removed them all and re-added, trying again now...

Comment: @CodeMonkey Afraid not. Still rejected! So frustrating! i've uploaded loads of apps, never had issues like this

Comment: @user2418516, the rejection is specifically refers to icon files that are not in png format, so I say check the project files on your computer again. I know it is frustrating, been there. But if you don't find that file you can't get your app off the ground. So I'm sorry to say the obvious but that is the only way.

Comment: What version of XCode are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the complexity/file size of your images. It sounds strange, but I've experienced this problem myself today.

Our 1024x1024 large app icon that had previously been fine was suddenly rejected. The icons we're using are quite simple (black and white company logo), so I added a little complexity to bring up the file size, and then the icon was accepted.

As the only difference was file size (dimensions, DPI, RGB format hadn't changed), I assume Apple is now checking for a minimum size for this icon, and it wouldn't surprise me if the same was being applied to the in-app icons.

Comment: Bingo. However the issue was the icon was in black and white. It required some colour, so i added a red dot in the top right that will be cropped when used on the device. It's now being accepted.

Comment: It's about color, not size.  I tried uploading a 3mb tiff version when I had this issue, and it still got rejected.

Comment: I can't believe that's the reason, but I've just managed to get my app accepted by putting a single red pixel at the top right corner as well. Crazy.

Comment: I have a grayscale icon that was not rejected, icon is RGB, but the image is mono-chromatic.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen images go corrupt sometimes, it is worth removing all of your app icons and adding them back to your project from the original source.

Also check your target's Info plist under the "Icon files" and "Icon files (iOS 5)" sections. Make sure they contain the correct filenames

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the comments, gave this ago early on, no such luck!

Comment: I thought this was what was happening to me. I just copied the png from my designer's assets directory into the source directory again. Should have just been the same file, git sees no difference in the files, the date on the file is older. However now the binary is accepted and the app goes into waiting for review. Odd.

Answer (score 1):

Set Architecture to "Standard (armv7, armv7s)", Base SDK to "Latest iOS (iOS 6.1)" and Deployment Target to "4.3", **or more recent**.

Binaries are now rejected if using armv6, SDK 5.1 and target below 4.3.

At time of writing Xcode version is 4.6.3.

Comment: Thanks! You have ended my 2 day 25x times submission agony. This has solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Open up your .ipa file and look for any extra images that may have been included.  The .ipa is just a zip file, so from the terminal, unzip it, eg:

```
unzip /path/to/myapp.ipa
```

You can also check your project in Xcode.  Select the project in the navigation pane, select the app target in the content pane, then go to the "build phases" tab and look at the "copy bundle resources" section.  Browse through it to find your "rogue" image.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error message earlier today and in my case it turned out that when your icon is completely in grayscale (has no colored pixels), it will automatically get rejected.  Unfortunately the message gives zero indication that this might be an issue.  Once I adjusted the color balance slightly towards red, I got to the next stage in review.

I ran into the same thing when I had submitted my "big icon" (1024x1024).  That was a little less mysterious, as they at least mentioned "RGB" color requirements.  Of course in normal language that still doesn't mean that grayscale is verboten, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

It was today exactly the same issue.
I tried to make the app with support iOS target 3.1.3 and support 6.1 using SDK 5.1 and 6.1 together. It was my usual success way.

So, my solution: to use the standard way with target iOS 4.3 without SDK 5.1.
Now it's in order. Well, sometimes it is not the problem with icons, but the using old SDK.